# Connecting iPhone Xr to a PC that doesn't have iTunes on it

Tags: iphone, windows

I'm trying to pull some video off a friend's iPhone.  It's an iPhone Xr, Software Version 12.2 according to the About screen.  I want to copy the video to a PC running Win7 SP1.  I don't own an iPhone, so I don't have iTunes on my PC, and I'm trying to avoid installing it.

I connect the phone to the PC and the phone prompts with "Trust this computer?"  I press Yes.  I look at my PC.  There's no popup on how to handle files like if you plug in an external device.  I look at My Computer in File Explorer, and there's no iPhone present.

Is there some setting or something I need to tinker with to get my PC to see the iPhone?

Comment: It's been a while since I tried this but I *THINK* you still need the appropriate drivers so the system will recognize it as an accessible storage device. Beats me, though, how you would get those drivers without installing iTunes. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding an answer in a YouTube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuJgHIipTvM

I will summarize in the event of link rot:

1. Connect the iPhone to the PC with a USB cable
2. Click the Start button in the lower left corner, and open the
   Devices and Printers window
3. At the bottom of the window you will see a section labeled
   "Unspecified"
4. Right click on Apple Mobile Device USB Driver and choose
   "Properties"
5. Click the "Hardware" tab, and then the "Properties" button
6. Click the "Change Settings" button
7. Click the "Driver" tab and then the "Update Driver" button.
8. Click the "Browse my computer" option, and then the "Let me pick
   from a list" option
9. Change to the MTP USB Device driver

It worked for me, after I did that I was able to see the iPhone attached to my PC.  I had to open and close the Windows Explorer window a couple times before it would actually let me see the DCIM folder on the iPhone, so don't get frustrated if it doesn't work right away.

Hope that helps anyone who might stop by and see this answer!